# How can i get this list centered

Tags: html, css

I want the tabs centered but not the content, i dont know how to center the headings

```
<ul class="tab" id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event,'Negatives')">Negatives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event, 'Positives')">Positives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event, 'Climate')">Climate Change</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event, 'Saving')">Saving Energy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what? What do you want to do? Show some CSS of what you've tried.

Comment: ive tried text-align center and <center> tags sorry

Comment: Provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to let us better understand you. And try to clearify `content` and `headings`: what do you mean?

Comment: i mean the link text in the <a> tags ie "negative" that is the heading im talking about

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to center align the list but keep the text left-aligned:

```
ul.tab {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}

.tab li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do. This is the way you can center the "tabs" using `display: inline-block`:

```css
.tab {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tab li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.tab li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab" id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event,'Negatives')">Negatives</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event, 'Positives')">Positives</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event, 'Climate')">Climate Change</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openClimate(event, 'Saving')">Saving Energy</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```